# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value using cloudkit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, icloud, cloudkit

I keep getting the following error :

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

and I guess I just don't understand why. Can someone please help me find my mistake? Is it that variable results is optional?

The error keeps pointing to a line in `viewDidLoad()`, I commented where. Thanks.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Physics Help!
//
//  Created by Sam Hanson on 2/8/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Sam Hanson. All rights reserved.
//


import UIKit
import CloudKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

//VARIABLES********************************************************

@IBOutlet var c1Answer: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var questions: UILabel!
var resultsOfDB : String = ""
var indexes : [Int] = []
var counter : Int = 0
var newStr : String = ""

//*****************************************************************




override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.questions.text = String(getNewQbutton()) //error points to here*********

}


//load the answers, grab them from the cloud base
@IBAction func loadAnswers() {
    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    var publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase

    let myQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "QuestionsTable", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))

    publicDB.performQuery(myQuery, inZoneWithID: nil){
        results, error in

        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        }

        else
        {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                self.c1Answer.text = results.description
                println(results.description)

            })
        }
    }

}




@IBAction func getNewQbutton() {

    let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
    var publicDB = container.publicCloudDatabase


    let myQuery = CKQuery(recordType: "QuestionsTable", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))


    publicDB.performQuery(myQuery, inZoneWithID: nil){
        results, error in

        if error != nil {
            println(error)
        }

        else
        {

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                self.resultsOfDB = results.description

                //for each character in resultsOfDB
                for character in self.resultsOfDB{

                    if(character == "\""){
                        self.indexes.append(self.counter)

                    }
                    self.counter++
                }

                self.newStr = self.resultsOfDB.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(start: advance(self.resultsOfDB.startIndex, self.indexes[0] + 1), end: advance(self.resultsOfDB.endIndex, -(self.counter - self.indexes[1]))))

                self.questions.text = self.newStr
            })
        }
        self.counter = 0
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There can be two reasons for this problem:

**1.**
This can mean that you are trying to call a function (`text`?) of an object (`questions`?) which is not initialized.

My guess is that `questions` is not initialized. So, when your call questions.text, you are calling text function on a nil outlet.

Make sure that your outlets `questions` are hooked up properly in the storyboard (you should see a circle near your `@IBOutlet`). Also, make sure you haven't set up multiple connections to your outlet.

**2.** 
Your function `getNewQbutton` is an `@IBAction` that returns nothing. So the statement `String(getNewQbutton())` doesn't make a lot of sense. Since your function `getNewQbutton` has no return type (and is an `@IBOutlet`), you are probably giving `nil` to String(). That may be the second reason of this issue.

Comment: I checked the connections from questions and it is only connected to one UILabel. Could it be that maybe somehow the function is putting a nil value into questions.text which is causing the error?

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured it out! Thank youuuu!